# No application window after VisualVM start

Tags: java, linux, ssh, visualvm

I want to connect to JVM running on remote CentOS 6 server using VisualVM installed on server. I connect to server using ssh with X forwarding:

```
ssh -X <user@ip>
```

My `~/.bashrc` exports these variables to run VisualVM:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_102/
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Then I run VisualVM locating on remote server:

```
/usr/local/visualvm_138/bin/visualvm
```

It invokes without errors, but there is no application view appeared (which should appear at application start). Also, there is no Applications sub-item inside Window menu item. I already ran VisualVM successfully using this way about month ago. How to make this window appeared?

Comment: What OS are you using for your local system? Is it running an X server? When you log into the remote system, what is the value of your DISPLAY environment variable? What happens when you run visualvm? It sounds like visualvm is displaying some kind of window, but it doesn't contain what you expect? Is this correct?

Comment: @Kenster

1. My local OS is CentOS too, it's running X server.
2. My DISPLAY equals to localhost:11.0.
3. Yes, it's correct. When I run visualvm, it displays almost empty window. There is only menu items (File, Edit, View, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to delete VisualVM userdir and cache and than restart VisualVM. Userdir is at `~/.visualvm/1.3.8` and cache is at `~/.cache/visualvm/1.3.8`

Comment: didn't work for me. Still the application window doesn't come up for me..:(

Comment: those using windows: userdir is in <user dir>/AppData/Roaming/visualvm while cache is in <user dir>/AppData/local/visualvm/